# Maven integration menu item disappeared from jenkins multibranch pipeline job page

Tags: jenkins, multibranch-pipeline

After some Jenkinsfile experiments, the 'Maven' item on the job page disappeared, and downstream projects are not triggered anymore.

My best guess is that the problem appeared after I changed the publisher settings.

I reduced and reduced the Jenkinsfile, but I cannot find a configuration that brings that Maven menu item back. My most minimal Jenkinsfile currently looks something like this (it builds successfully and deploys to our Nexus repository):

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

node(label: 'mac') {
      
  checkout(scm: scm)

  withMaven(
    maven: 'maven',
    jdk: 'jdk8',
    traceability: true,
    //publisherStrategy: 'EXPLICIT', 
    //options: [pipelineGraphPublisher(), mavenLinkerPublisher()],
  ) {
      sh "mvn -e -U clean deploy" 
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I gotten bitten by this: https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-71949